# Estimating an integrand

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, estimation, oscillatory-integral

Given an integral
$$\int_1^T \frac{f(t)}{t} \, {\rm d}t$$
where $f(t)$ is oscillating and I want to make an estimate I can do the following
$$\left|\int_1^T \frac{f(t)}{t} \, {\rm d}t\right| \leq \int_1^T \left|\frac{f(t)}{t}\right| \, {\rm d}t \leq \int_1^T |f(t)| \, {\rm d}t$$
but this is not enough. Is this even possible:
$$\left|\int_1^T \frac{f(t)}{t} \, {\rm d}t\right| \leq \left|\int_1^T f(t) \, {\rm d}t \right|\, ? $$

Comment: Do you know anything else about the function $f$? And how does it oscillate?

Comment: You can assume it is periodic and bounded.

Comment: The last inequality cannot be true in general.

Comment: Can you come up with a counterexample?

Comment: $f(t)=\cos(t-1)$ and $T=2 \pi +1$. The RHS is $0$ while the LHS is not (make a drawing if you are not convinced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last step can only be done on intervals with fixed sign. So, you have to split an oscillating function into positive and negative domains, and you get

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{|f(t)|}{t}dt\leq \frac{1}{x_1}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\left|f(t)\right|dt$$
where $x_2>x_1>0$.

The entire integral is then an alternating sum of such terms -- this is the reason why it doesn't work in general. In alternating sums, if you change the magnitude of some terms, you can get any value (imagine if the inequality was exact for positive terms but for negative, they just become zero?)

Let's define

$$a_n=\int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}\frac{|f(t)|}{t}dt$$
$$b_n=\int_{x_n}^{x_{n+1}}|f(t)|dt$$
where $x_n$ are zeros of $f(t)$.

Your statement is, that

$$\sum (-1)^n b_n$$
is bounded, and you want to prove that
$$\sum (-1)^n a_n$$
is bounded, too.

But that is exactly the Dirichlet test that says (bounded alternating)×(monotonically decreasing to zero)=(convergent).

In our case, the bounded alternating series is $(-1)^n b_n$ and the monotonically decreasing to zero is $1/x_n$, resulting in a statement for $a_n$ which is bounded by the product of these two.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: But it still seems to hold that if $$\int_1^T f(t) \, {\rm d}t$$ is bounded for $T\rightarrow \infty$ then so is $$\int_1^T \frac{f(t)}{t} \, {\rm d}t$$ but I can not justify it with the estimates.

Comment: I added the reference to alternating series test.

Comment: `But that is exactly the alternating series test that says (convergent alternating)×(monotonically decreasing to zero)=(convergent)`: How are any of the $a_n$ or $b_n$ monotonically decreasing? Because of the periodicity $a_n$ might contain a monotonically decreasing subsequence, but is that helpful? Since from a specific $a_n$ we have 1 negative and 1 positive part that monotonically decreasing subsequence will appear with the same sign! It's not like I can bound that sum from above as in positive sums: $$\sum_n a_n \leq \sum_n b_n \, .$$

Comment: Set $b_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and consider the $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n b_n$$ which converges by Leibniz criterium. Now set $a_{2n-1}=0$ and $a_{2n}=\frac{1}{2n}$ with $n=1,2,3,...$. Clearly $a_n\leq b_n$ but $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n a_n =\infty \, .$$ It is similar above. My sequences are not monotonic.

Comment: The $1/x_n$ term is decreasing! $(-1)^n b_n$ is just convergent alternating sequence, and $ a_n<b_n/x_n$ gives another, smaller alternating sequence.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I think you can not argue with monotonically decreasing.

Comment: I was referring to the Dirichlet's test, I didn't recall the name of the test correctly, see corretions and link.

Comment: Right! I guess that is what I was looking for. So the keyword here is summation by parts. Thanks